# Advicing message not working

Tags: elisp, defadvice

```
(defun my-message (format-string &rest args)
  (apply 'message
         (concat "my-message: " format-string)
         args))

(my-message "abc %d" 123)
;; ==> "my-message: abc 123"
(message "abc %d" 123)
;; ==> "abc 123"

(advice-add 'message :around 'my-message)
;;(advice-remove 'message 'my-message)
```

After `advice-add` to `message`, an error `Wrong type argument: sequencep, #<subr message>` is signaled. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `:around` advice, your `my-message` function is getting the original function as its first argument. Your code is missing this argument and is instead treating the first argument as the message format string. Change your `my-message` to specify the additional argument:

```
(defun my-message (orig-fun format-string &rest args)
  (apply orig-fun
         (concat "my-message: " format-string)
         args))
```

and then the advice will work as expected. Note how this version calls `orig-fun` instead of hard-coding `'message` as the `apply` target.

You don't need `:around` advice for this case, though. All you're doing is modifying the format string, so you could instead use `:filter-args`, which allows you to modify arguments before they're passed to the original function. Here's an example that works for your case:

```
(defun my-message (args)
  (nconc (list (concat "my-message: " (car args))) (cdr args)))
(advice-add 'message :filter-args #'my-message)
```

Comment: Thanks for the `:filter-args` advice. Really helpful.